# MATLAB - Generate square signal in ODE15s function?

Tags: matlab, signals, solver, ode

I'm trying to generate a square signal from inside a function, run through an ODE15s solver. The problem is, that the output is not square, but rather linear.

```
function dX = test(t ,X )

y = X (1)  ;


a = 24;
dc = 50;
k = 2;

f=k*2*pi;
y=a*square(f*t,dc);


% derivative vector 

dX = [ y ]';
```

The run script:

```
[t , X ]= ode15s ( @test ,[0 10] , [0]) ;

figure (1);
plot(t ,X)
```

Are there any way to implement a square function inside the ode function? I need the value inside the function, and therefore can't call it from the runscript, as it is a function of the time, t.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by "square function"? how does your `square` implementation look like?

Comment: @m.s., `square` is part of the Signal Processing Toolbox

Comment: Btw., the output of the solver should of course not be a square wave, but a triangle wave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial answer: If you put the line

```
fprintf('%g\t%g\n', t, y)
```

into your function `test`, you will see that the solver calls the function only at values of `t` where `y` is 24:

```
0   24
0   24
0   24
1.57072e-14 24
1   24
2   24
3   24
4   24
5   24
6   24
7   24
8   24
9   24
10  24
```

I don't know why `ode15s` does that. Things can be a bit improved by using `ode45` instead, but the result is still not perfect.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Yes, i am familiar with the fact that a square wave is related to lot of discontinuity. And thus, it makes sense that it gets spiked.